# Posting a date column in Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I'm stuck on what should be a very simple question, which is frustrating me greatly.

Essentially, I'm sorting through many files and manipulating them, but am stuck on this: how do I add in a column with something like the date in every cell down to the end of where the other columns have data?

Say that there are 5 other columns with length of 20 each. What code would I use to make column 6 have a certain value with a length of 20? The length varies with each sheet I work on, and this has been the problem.

In a program like MATLAB, I could just denote this by putting something like F1:end, but finding the answer for Excel is driving me crazy!

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It would help others if you could post some code that you have already tried, where in the code the issue is, and what, if any, error message you're getting when you run the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In VBA you would typically look from the bottom up to find the last non-blank cell in a column. With this, you can get the `.Row` to concatenate into a [Range object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838238.aspx) definition. Example:

```
with activesheet
    .range("F1:F" & .cells(rows.count, 5).end(xlup).row) = Format(Now, "dd-mmm-yyyy  hh:mm")
end with
```

This will fill column F from the first row to the cell in column F that is next to the last non-blank value in column E.

Answer (score 1):

You could programmatically do this in vb to detect the bottom row with a value in, though it sounds as though you might be after a more straight forwards working solution.

Type a value in the top row, and with the cell selected you should see a square in the bottom right of the cell, double click it to fill to the end of the used range.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub Tester()

    With ActiveSheet
        .Range(.Range("E1"), _
               .Cells(Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp)).Offset(0, 1).Value = Date
    End With

End Sub
```